# Mantle ignore key in JSON

Tags: swift, model, mapping, github-mantle, modelmapper

I've been trying to ignore a key inside a dictionary when creating my mantle model.
Let's say that the json contains:

```
{
    prop1:"my prop",
    prop2:"my prop2"
}
```

initially I have a model with

```
class MyModel: MTLModel, MTLJSONSerializing {


    //MARK: Model properties

    var prop1: String!

    class func JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]! {

        return ["prop1":"prop1"]
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error saying " this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key prop2".

I also noticed that the `JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey` method is not called when initialising the model with a dictionary `try! super.init(dictionary: dictionaryValue, error: ())`, only when generating JSON from the model forcing the properties to have the same key as the JSON.
The reason why I want to be able to ignore certain keys is because the backend service might change and I don't necessarily HAVE to roll an update because some extra info has been added to the call or because they simply are completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't using the `MTLJSONAdapter`, instead I was doing an `init(dictionary: dictionaryValue, error: ())`. 
The correct way is to use `MTLJSONAdapter.modelOfClass(MyClass.self, fromJSONDictionary: aDictionary, error: ());` this way the `JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey` method is in fact used.